# Why is the value of yy and er1 -1.#IND for this VHDL code? Whats wrong?

Tags: vhdl

Why is the value of yy and er1 -1.#IND for this VHDL code? Whats wrong?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.math_real.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_Unsigned.ALL;

use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity random is
    generic ( width : integer :=  32; 
    nn:natural:=1; --power of the binomial distribution <16
    m:REAL:=0.0     -- mean output value

    ); 
port (
      clk : in std_logic;
      random_num : out std_logic_vector (width-1 downto 0);   --output vector
      RST : in STD_LOGIC;
      DATA_OUT : out REAL:=0.0            
    );
end random;

architecture Behavioral of random is
        type arri is array (0 to 15) of integer;
        type arrr is array (0 to 15) of real;
        signal noisysignal1:real;
        signal a : integer := 0;
        signal yy : real;
        signal er1 : real;

begin
process(clk,rst)
variable rand_temp : std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0):=(width-1 => '1',others => '0');
variable temp : std_logic := '0';

 variable s1:arri:=(3,33,333,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,others=>55);
 variable s2:arri:=(5,55,555,50,6,7,8,9,5,6,7,21,33,others=>22);
 variable r:arrr:=(others=>0.0);
 variable s:real:=0.0;

 variable y,er : real;
 variable w1,w2 : real :=0.0;
 variable u : real:= 0.002;

 variable noisysignal:real;

begin
if rst='1' then
DATA_OUT<=0.0;
elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then

temp := rand_temp(width-1) xor rand_temp(width-2);
rand_temp(width-1 downto 1) := rand_temp(width-2 downto 0);
rand_temp(0) := temp;

s:=0.0;
for i in 0 to nn-1 loop    -- nn noise generators
                   UNIFORM (s1(i),s2(i),r(i));
                   s:=s+r(i);
        end loop;
            DATA_OUT <= 2.0*(s/real(nn)-0.5)+ m;
            noisysignal:=real(to_integer(signed(rand_temp)))+( 2.0*(s/real(nn)-0.5)+ m);
            noisysignal1<=noisysignal;
            if(a<1000) then
            y:=noisysignal*w1;--+noisysignal1'last_value * w2;
            yy<=y;
            er:=y-real(to_integer(signed(rand_temp)));
            if(er<0.0)then
               er:=-er;
            end if;
            er1<=er;
            w1:=u*noisysignal1*er+w1;
            w2:=u*noisysignal1'last_value*er+w2;
            a<=a+1;
            end if;

end if;
random_num <= rand_temp;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Simple debugging can answer this. Learn some debugging techniques. Assert the values before and after assignments to `yy,er. Initialise them to `0.0` before simulation. If they go wrong after assignment, test the values you are assigning to them the same way, and repeat until you get valid inputs to some step, and invalid outputs. Then fix that step. There have been many recent poor quality questions asked about this piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean) post, -1.#IND means you got a non-real number. In the providing blog post, they example they use for that particular error is taking the root of a negative number. What you should look for is possibilities for yy or er1 to be assigned non-real numbers, such square-root operations where its possible that the input is negative.

Also beyond that, I hope you don't plan on using this outside of Simulation, because one of the big drawbacks of the math_real library is that it doesn't synthesize.